# css hide left panel when autocomplete is active

Tags: javascript

I want to hide left panel when clicking the "TEXT", and also when an item is searched from autocomplete search box. So my aim is to not overlap the autocomplete items and panel.
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zzzzz/get0d9ro/7/

```
 temp = 1;
        $("#label").on('click', function(){
        if(temp == 1){
            $('#panellist').toggle();
            temp = 0;
        }
        else{
                temp = 1;
                $('#panellist').toggle();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your binding in a `$(document).ready()` handler if you want to place it above the element itself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temp = 1;
    $("#label").on('click', function(){
        if(temp == 1){
            $('#panellist').toggle();
            temp = 0;
        }
        else{
                temp = 1;
                $('#panellist').toggle();
        }
    });
});
```